# ASP.NET Textbox align text left to right in a right to left webpage

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, right-to-left

I have a website that is supposed to have a right to left alignment. I have installed the Right to Left version of the bootstrap and it works well.

The alignment also affects the text in the Textboxes. I want to add a Css class or something that would make the text in the TextBoxes be aligned Left to Right while keeping the rest of the components Right to Left.

I have tried to add

```
text-align: left; 
direction:ltr;
```

To the textbox css but it doesn't affect the text at all.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding `!important;` to your style:

```
text-align: left !important;
direction:ltr !important;
```

It may be because there are already styles forcing right to left. `important!;` will over-ride these.

Have you tried applying it directly to the textbox?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tb" CssClass="align-left" runat="server" />

.align-left {
     text-align: left !important;
}
```